# Is it possible to put two functions in densityplot like in the plot?

Tags: plotting

Simply, I have these two density plots below, I would like to show the two spots of light in the same figure.  I used `Show[f1,f2]` but it did not work?!

```
ψ[x0_, y0_] = 1/(50 Sqrt[2 π])Exp[-((x - x0)^2/(2 50^2) + (y - y0)^2/(2 50^2))];

f1 = DensityPlot[{ψ[500, 500]}, {x, -1000,1000}, {y, -1000, 1000}, PlotPoints -> 100,ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRange -> All]  

f2 = DensityPlot[{ψ[-500, -500]}, {x, -1000, 1000}, {y, -1000,1000}, PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",PlotRange -> All]  

Show[f1,f2]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: how about add the two functions and do one plot?

Comment: @george2079, it did not work also-:)

Comment: `Show` puts the two plots on-top of each other. Try, e.g., `f2 = DensityPlot[{\[Psi][-500, -500]}, {x, -1000, 0}, {y, -1000, 0}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  PlotRange -> All]` and both "spots" are present in the output of `Show[f1, f2]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider a [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) of two functions to be similar to a [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) of two functions viewed from the top, then

```
DensityPlot[
 Max[ψ[-500, -500], ψ[500, 500]], {x, -1000, 1000}, {y, -1000, 1000}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Out]

gives you the expected output.

---

This also works for functions with overlapping features:

```
DensityPlot[Max[Sin[x], Cos[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Out]

The corresponding `Plot3D` for comparison:

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Top]
```

[image: Out]

However, if your expect a "`DensityPlot` of two function" to give you the total combined density, then [using `Plus` instead of `Max`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140688/18476) is the appropriate approach.

In more involved visualization situations one can use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) to combine the two functions in one `DensityPlot` or create two `DensityPlot`s, restrict each to a certain area using the [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) option or by specifying a region ([documentation examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html#272043783)), and then combine both using `Show`.

Answer (score 5):

I like [Jason B.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140688/34008).
Here is a quick to type in alternative:

```
ImageAdd[Image[f1], Image[f2]]
```

[image]

Note that the axes ticks and values get blurry.

I assume in other cases this would be better:

```
ImageAdjust[ImageAdd[Image[f1], Image[f2]]]
```

Comment: Very nice - so does `ImageAdd` do something like `Image[ImageData[img1] + ImageData[img2]]`?

Comment: Thank you all! It is very nice now

Comment: @JasonB. I guess -- that code also works.

Comment: This works exceptionally well for the given `ColorFunction`, but might get a little odd with others.

Answer (score 1):

Now I also find an interesting solution

```
ψ[x0_, y0_] = 1/(50 Sqrt[2 π]) Exp[-((x - x0)^2/(2 50^2) + (y - y0)^2/(2 50^2))]; 
f1 = DensityPlot[{ψ[500, 500]}, {x, -1000, 1000}, {y, -1000, 1000}, PlotPoints -> 100,  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0], RGBColor[0.6, 0, 0, 1]}, #] &), PlotRange -> All];
f2 = DensityPlot[{ψ[-500, -500]}, {x, -1000, 1000}, {y, -1000, 1000}, PlotPoints -> 100,  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0], RGBColor[0.6, 0, 0, 1]}, #] &), PlotRange -> All];
Show[f1, f2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit2:** @Karsten 7. suggestion also works

```
ψ[x0_, y0_] =1/(50 Sqrt[
           2 π]) Exp[-((x - x0)^2/(2 50^2) + (y - y0)^2/(2 50^2))];

f1 = DensityPlot[ψ[500, 500], {x, -1000, 1000}, {y,-1000, 1000}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRange -> All]

f2 = DensityPlot[ψ[-500, -500], {x, -1000, 0}, {y, -1000, 0}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  PlotRange -> All]

Show[f1, f2]
```

Here is an alternative way. First change the domain of each plot.

```
f1 = DensityPlot[ψ[500, 500], {x, 0, 1000}, {y, 0, 1000}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRange -> All]

f2 = DensityPlot[ψ[-500, -500], {x, -1000, 0}, {y, -1000, 0}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  PlotRange -> All]

Show[f1, f2]
```

[image]

Now we can add black background.

```
Show[f1, f2, Prolog -> {Black, Rectangle[{-1000, -1000}, {1000, 1000}]}]
```

[image]

Or you can use @george2079 suggestion in comment

```
DensityPlot[ψ[-500, -500]+ψ[500, 500], {x, -1000, 
  1000}, {y, -1000, 1000}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRange -> All]
```

> Same result